# How do you access tree depth in Python's scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree, depth

I'm using scikit-learn to create a Random Forest. However, I want to find the individual depths of each tree. It seems like a simple attribute to have but according to the documentation, (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) there is no way of accessing it.

If this isn't possible, is there a way of accessing the tree depth from a Decision Tree model?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Each instance of `RandomForestClassifier` has an `estimators_` attribute, which is a list of [`DecisionTreeClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier) instances. The documentation shows that an instance of `DecisionTreeClassifier` has a `tree_` attribute, which is an instance of the (undocumented, I believe) `Tree` class. Some exploration in the interpreter shows that each `Tree` instance has a `max_depth` parameter which *appears* to be what you're looking for -- again, it's undocumented.

In any case, if `forest` is your instance of `RandomForestClassifier`, then:

```
>>> [estimator.tree_.max_depth for estimator in forest.estimators_]
[9, 10, 9, 11, 9, 9, 11, 7, 13, 10]
```

should do the trick.

Each estimator also has a [`get_depth()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.get_depth) method than can be used to retrieve the same value with briefer syntax:

```
>>> [estimator.get_depth() for estimator in forest.estimators_]
[9, 10, 9, 11, 9, 9, 11, 7, 13, 10]
```

---

To avoid mixup, it should be noted that there is an attribute of each estimator (and not each estimator's `tree_`) called `max depth` which returns the setting of the parameter rather than the depth of the actual tree. How `estimator.get_depth()`, `estimator.tree_.max_depth`, and `estimator.max_depth` relate to each other is clarified in the example below:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=3, random_state=4, max_depth=6)
iris = load_iris()
clf.fit(iris['data'], iris['target'])
[(est.get_depth(), est.tree_.max_depth, est.max_depth) for est in clf.estimators_]
```

Out:

```
[(6, 6, 6), (3, 3, 6), (4, 4, 6)]
```

Setting max depth to the default value `None` would allow the first tree to expand to depth 7 and the output would be:

```
[(7, 7, None), (3, 3, None), (4, 4, None)]
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is exactly what I have been looking for. Similarly, do you know if there is a way to manually delete a particular tree from the random forest? I am trying to delete trees with less than a certain depth.

Comment: It *might* be as simple as deleting the estimators from the list. That is, to delete the first tree, `del forest.estimators_[0]`. Or to only keep trees with depth 10 or above: `forest.estimators_ = [e for e in forest.estimators_ if e.tree.max_depth >= 10]`. But it doesn't look like `RandomForestClassifier` was built to work this way, and by modifying `forest.estimators_` you might break things. You can try it out and see if the results seem reasonable, though. If you do, you might want to update `forest.n_estimators = len(forest.estimators_)` for good measure.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, this tells you the the maximum _allowed_ depth of each tree in the forest, not the actual depth. So for example a random forest trained with `max_depth=10` will return: ```[10, 10, 10, ...]```

Comment: It returns whichever is lower of the max_depth argument and the actual depth value.

Comment: See https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/19842/anyway-to-know-all-details-of-trees-grown-using-randomforestclassifier-in-scikit/36228#36228 to get the actual max depth for each tree in a forest.

Comment: @jme - If I understood this correctly, then the maximum depth for the example is 11? By default the `DecisionTreeClassifier` takes `max_depth` if no value is provided.

Comment: @JonathanSimon I believe your comment is inaccurate. If you check the docs of the DecisionTreeClassifier https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.get_depth, you will see that it has a `get_depth()` method, which "Returns the depth of the decision tree". If you click to view the source of this method, you can see that it returns `self.tree_.max_depth`...

Comment: A quick test with the iris example on the same doc page shows that changing the `max_depth` parameter only influences `tree_.max_depth` if it is lower than the depth the tree would otherwise expand to, as @KenFehling wrote above.